# UTF-8 characters get saved as ?? on insert, but gets saved correctly on update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, utf-8

I have a table on MS SQLServer with an nVarchar column. I am saving a UTF-8 character using an insert statement. It gets saved as ???. If I update the same column using the same value via an update statement, it gets saved correctly.

Any hint on what would be the issue here? The collation used is : SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Show your insert statement. There is - quite probably - an `N` missing:

```
DECLARE @v NVARCHAR(100)='Some Hindi from Wikipedia मानक हिन्दी';
SELECT @v;
```

Result: `Some Hindi from Wikipedia ???? ??????`

```
SET @v=N'Some Hindi from Wikipedia मानक हिन्दी';
SELECT @v;
```

Result: `Some Hindi from Wikipedia मानक हिन्दी`

The `N` in front of the string literal tells SQL-Server to interpret the content as `unicode` (to be exact: as `ucs-2`). Otherwise it will be treated as a *1-byte-encoded extended ASCII*, which is not able to deal with all characters...

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply... But for another table with similar structure and collation, it inserts correctly without having the N prefix. I was wondering what could be the reason here.

Comment: @Supriya Simple answer: **Don't do it!** If you rely on the system's abilities to read your text properly it might work and next time it won't... Dealing with `NVARCHAR` should **always** be done with literals with `N'Some string'`. Otherwise it's gambling...

Comment: Thanks again for your quick answer... I created an exact copy of the table having the issue and the insert statement worked fine there. Then I checked with few other tables on the schema (all of nvarchar) and they work fine too in a consistent manner. So I fail to understand whats the special issue with this particular table?  I get your point that we need to prefix N. But I am trying this insert from java and it still beats me how it works consistently on the other tables.  The insert statement is insert into table1 (c1,c2,c3) values ('','','') where the value is set to greek characters.

Comment: @Supriya, please poste the (reduced) table's definition, and the insert statement. Might be a trigger involved? Any kind of function, which might manipulate the value before the assignment?

Comment: @Shungo, Bingo... there was an insert trigger with some specific logic which was causing the problem... Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Supriya and Shungo: the advice to prefix string literals with a capital-`N` is correct, but the explanation in the final paragraph of this answer is incorrect. Yes, the `N` does indicate that the literal is "Unicode", but it is specifically the UTF-16 Little Endian encoding. Also, regarding the statement about UTF-8: a) UTF-8 is just another encoding of Unicode -- it is just as much Unicode as UTF-16, b) there is no UTF-8 anywhere in SQL Server, and c) not having the `N` prefix means that the literal is 8-bit Extended ASCII of whatever code page is associated with the DB's default Collation.