# How to handle invalid character in 'sp_xml_preparedocument' (SQL Server 20188 R2)

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure where I am using sp_xml_preparedocument to handle XML data. But due to some invalid characters like

```
Ex: 1. INGENIERÍA
    2. Engineer'
```

in XML data, SQL throws an exception as "An invalid character can be found in the text content".

[image: Screen shot of the exception attached]

My Stored procedure look like

```
    DECLARE @idoc INT
    DECLARE @doc XML
    SET @doc = @DocElements -- @Docelements will have XML data
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc

    SELECT BadgeNo FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/DocumentElement/PEScoreUpdate',2) WITH(BadgeNo  VARCHAR(50)))AND
    ASRYEAR=YEAR(GETDATE()) And IsPlanDeleted<>1
    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

Sampel XML data

```
  <DocumentElement>
  <PEScoreUpdate>
    <Badge_x0020_No>105731</Badge_x0020_No>       
    <Last_x0020_Name>Vijaya Kumar</Last_x0020_Name>
    <First_x0020_Name>Sanjay Kumar</First_x0020_Name>
    <BOC>Onshore E&amp;C</BOC>
    <Emp_x0020_Class>White Collar</Emp_x0020_Class>
    <Site>INGENIERÍA PROJECT     Secondment</Site>       
  </PEScoreUpdate>
</DocumentElement>
```

I am getting this XML data from an excel sheet with thousands of data so, it's practically not possible to search for invalid text and correct it manually.
Anyone guide me how to handle this invalid char in SQL procedure. Is there any way to replace this invalid character but I am processing thousands of data. will it affect performance? 
Anyone guide me. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One point is, that `FROM OPENXML` (together with the SPs to prepare and remove a dcoument) is outdated and should not be used any more (rare exceptions exist).

To your actual question:

I'm pretty sure, that this issue is not related to `FROM OPENXML`, neither to `sp_xml_preparedocument`. You did not show, how you are passing in the XML. But - assumeably - you do this on string-level with a `VARCHAR` variable (or with an XML-literal. Try to use `NVARCHAR` or place a leading `N` before you literal.

If I'm right, you find details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42683643/5089204

### UPDATE How to read XML today...

Try to read your XML like this

```
DECLARE @doc XML=
N'<DocumentElement>
  <PEScoreUpdate>
    <Badge_x0020_No>105731</Badge_x0020_No>       
    <Last_x0020_Name>Vijaya Kumar</Last_x0020_Name>
    <First_x0020_Name>Sanjay Kumar</First_x0020_Name>
    <BOC>Onshore E&amp;C</BOC>
    <Emp_x0020_Class>White Collar</Emp_x0020_Class>
    <Site>INGENIERÍA PROJECT     Secondment</Site>       
  </PEScoreUpdate>
</DocumentElement>';

SELECT u.value(N'(Badge_x0020_No)[1]',N'int') AS Badge_x0020_No
      ,u.value(N'(First_x0020_Name)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS First_x0020_Name
      ,u.value(N'(BOC)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS BOC
      ,u.value(N'(Emp_x0020_Class)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Emp_x0020_Class
      ,u.value(N'(Site)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS [Site]
FROM @doc.nodes(N'/DocumentElement/PEScoreUpdate') AS A(u)
```

### UPDATE 2

Your code shows `/DocumentElement/BasicInformation` as `XPath`, but this doesn't show up in your XML?

Furthermore, the `_x0020_` within your elements names is coming from blanks in your Excel's columns names.

There are several places, where your issue might come from...

Comment: How should I read an xml file with the following format? It just has one node, e.g. <row Id="1" Post="Yes I am" Date="2019-04-01" /> and each row is like this.

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey A comment is not the best place for an entirely new question... Please start a new question. You can place a link in comments to alert people who might know the answer... But sure enough such a question will be answered in minutes.